# Save enviroment PATH once I added one

Tags: 13.04, command-line, bash, android, environment-variables

I'm trying to add an environment path for android studio, and I've done the following steps:

- checking is there is already: `echo $PATH`
- add my path: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/Programs/android-studio/bin/`
- check if have been added: `echo $PATH`
  and it was added correctly.

Then I close the terminal and reopen. If I do the check now `echo $PATH` there isn't the my path.

How should I save the changes in the environment path?

Answer (score 2):

I think you inserted the `export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/Programs/android-studio/bin/` in your terminal. But if you export the new path in terminal it lasts until you close the terminal. To add the path permanently add the following line at the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/Programs/android-studio/bin/
```

by opening it from terminal as,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add the line and save it. Next run in terminal,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

done.

Comment: Maybe you should try

". ~/.bashrc" instead of "source ~/.bashrc" in this answer.


Please note that there is a space between the "." and "~/.bashrc"

Comment: @akki `.` is the alias for `source`, is not it?

Comment: I have done it, but like before when I restart the terminal the command `echo $PATH` returns the list of paths without my one.

Comment: @souravc I dont know that exactly but I have personally seen the dot to work where source doesnt make the changes permanently until I reboot...

Comment: I have tried it in both ways

Comment: @giacomotb You have to open a new terminal to see the changes once you have run the command

Comment: @souravc I have checked into a new terminal, but the results are the same

Comment: @giacomotb are you using ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: no, I'm using 12.04

Answer (score 0):

You can add your path to global environment variables `/etc/environment` .
This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.

Comment: now in my enviroment file there is the line `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ubuntu/Programs/android-studio/bin"` but if I chech with an 'echo $PATH` the last path(my one) isn't present

Comment: After adding to the path in /etc/environment, you'll need to log out of your user session and back in. After that, it should pick up the new path.